# Js printing the first row alone when doing hide/show tr

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have two tables. I want to achieve the show/hide for the sub rows. I can able to get corresponding main and sub row via php. for example

```
ID      Field1   Field2

01        xxx      xxx

01        yyy      yyy

02        zzz      zzz

02        abc       abc

02        xyz      xyz
```

Above table structure 01 xxx 02 zzz zzz are from table1 others are from table 2. I have buttons for each main rows. when I click the button the corresponding sub rows will appear. The problem is when I click the button the `JS` returns only the first row. I'm stuck with that. help me

My PHP CODE:(SORRY for the huge code)

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', '');
$select1 =mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM ai");


while ($rownew=mysqli_fetch_array($select1)) 
{

?>
<input type='button' id="row_show_button<?php echo $rownew['idactionitems'];?>" value=<?php echo $rownew['idactionitems']?> onclick="ai_row_show_button('<?php echo $rownew['idactionitems'];?>');">
#some table datas here
</tr>
<?php 

 $new = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM rowai WHERE idactionitemsFK =".$rownew['idactionitems']);


     while($newrow1=mysqli_fetch_array($new)) 
     {

?>

<tr style="display:" id="trhide<?php echo $newrow1['idactionitemsFK'];?>">
<td id="txt_name_edit1<?php echo $newrow1['idactionitemsFK'];?>"><?php echo $newrow1['idactionitemsFK'];?></td>
<td id="txt_name_edit2<?php echo $newrow1['idactionitemsFK'];?>"><?php echo $newrow1['row'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
         }
}

?>
```

JS CODE:

```
function ai_row_show_button(idactionitems) {
    var trhide = document.getElementById("trhide"+idactionitems);
    //alert (trhide);
       if (trhide.style.display == "none") {
           <?php
$newsc = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM rowai WHERE idactionitemsFK = idactionitemsFK ");

    #
     while($newrow1=mysqli_fetch_array($newsc)) 
     {         
           ?>
        trhide.style.display = "block";
     <?php } ?>
         } else {
        trhide.style.display = "none";

    }
}
```

The solution I'm looking for is when I click the button that is generated by the first table, The value of the button passed to the `JS` function and give the all `<tr>` which are in the second table that is matching with the ID. Currently I'm receiving first row only. Please help me

Comment: call JS function that will consume the arguments(idactionitem) and produce the table data  there.

Comment: Aroon I have made some changes. Plz help me